# trigger auto mail on change value in particular cell

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am using a google spreadsheet which looks like:

```
   A             B                    C             D
1 Name        e-mail              Identifer       Status
2 Alex       ax@gmail.com         ERT ER          A
3 Micke      miike477@gmail.com   Ejyu er w       
4 John       john7788@tri.com     Arb Ed          C
```

I have a drop down list in column `D` (let say A,B & C for example), now i want that whenever the value changes (Initially the column `D` would be blank) in column `D` against a particular `Name` than an automatic e-mail trigger to e-mail id mentioned in column `B` by below mentioned sender id and content.

The email should be trigger whenever value changes in column `D` except for the blank, and if there were previously value was "B" and now it change to "C" than mail should be trigger.

Sender-example@gmail.com
CC-test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com

E-mail Body:

Hi Alex (`Should be picked from column A depending against which name e-mail trigger`)

some sentence here.
some sentence here with your **ERT ER** (`Should be pick from column C`) has status **A** (`should be pick from column D`).

Regards,
example
123456789

Comment: You should make a function onEdit() that checks the line and sends the email with the data.

Comment: @Liora Haydont I am not much familiar with google script...Please help me here so that accordingly i can tweak in the script.

Comment: @Liora Haydont In fact I don't know how auto email trigger in google script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 thing. You want to detect when the user changed the column D and you want to send an email.

#### 1. detect the change

There is a really cool built in function called `onEdit(event)` ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events))
With your event param, you'll be able to detect which column was affected by the script.

```
function onEdit(event){
    if(event.range.getColumn() == 4){ //A -> 1, B -> 2, etc
        //send the email here
    }
}
```

#### 2. send the email

There is also a really cool built in function called `sendMail()` ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body)). You could do something like

```
function sendMyEmail(line){
    var sendTo = //get value from column B
    var subject = //whatever subject you want
    var content = //get value from column A and C
    MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo,
        subject,
        content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks...Just want to know how to get value from column. If you can provide an example.

Comment: 4 is the equivalent of D (the 4th letter of the alphabet)

Comment: And what if there is something `High` as Value in column `D`.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I mean what if I have words in Column D other than letters like A B C than that ==4 doesn't work???

Comment: `event.range.getColumn()` return the column of the range that was edited, not the value

Comment: @VectorJX you need to review your JavaScript and Apps Script documentation. This is not a tutorial site. You are expected to put in effort to learn, on your own, especially given the plethora of existing examples and tutorials for both Javascript and Apps Script.